# how to move 2d objects on firemonkey platform?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a VCL application which can do the followings: the user can select various shapes from a toolbar
(rectangle, circle, user definied objects) and can move (and put) on the scene (on an TImage).
The moving implemented with xor mode TPen modes. The objects are not filled. How to do that with firemonkey? (I have not found xor mode pen modes on the firemonkey platform)

Comment: They don't exist. I think. Use different solution.

Comment: Draw the shape in a solid pen

Comment: Ok but how to move the object? I have to delete (undraw) the previous position (that was xor pen on VCL)

Comment: It's nothing like VCL. Don't try to put VCL solutions onto FMX. Try to learn how to do it the FMX way. This question isn't really going anywhere because you are asking about xor pen which isn't there.

Comment: Ok how should do that with FMX..?

Comment: Yes I searched the web but Im lost. You mean for example FMX.Objects.TRectangle?

Comment: Yes, a `TRectangle` for instance. Do you know how to add new controls to a form?

Comment: Yes I know... What is the position (to move) of FMX.Objects.TRectangle? (I dont see). Also I have to do that runtime.. can I do that? So I cant put this shapes design time..

Comment: Create a control at runtime in the usual way. Call its constructor and set its `Parent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no xor pen in FMX so far as I know. FMX is a very different framework from VCL and you would be best advised to find FMX solutions to problems rather than trying to code the way you coded the VCL.

So, you want a shape on a form. Start by adding one. For instance a `TRectange` or a `TCircle` control. Add shape controls to the form just as you would add list boxes or memos. The shapes can be found in the Shapes section of the toolbox, but in the more recent versions of Delphi you just type into the search box to find a control.

Once you've added the shape controls to the form you move them by modifying their `Position` property. For instance:

```
Circle1.Position.X := Circle1.Position.X + 5;
```

That's all there is to it.

As an alternative to that you can paint the shapes yourself if you prefer. Use the `OnPaint` event of the form, or add a `TPaintBox` and implement the painting in its `OnPaint` event handler.

To be quite honest with you, this is probably the way you should have been doing it even in the VCL. Using xor painting on the canvas of a `TImage` is not very practical.